# Why my code doesn't allow specific symbols?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using this code to allow only digits to type in textbox but now I want to allow `.` too. I modified this code but not working.

```
function isNumberKeyDotAllowed(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode == 46)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

TextBox declaration in markup:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxApplicantCNICNo"
    onkeypress="return isNumberKeyDotAllowed(this)" AutoPostBack=True 
    OnTextChanged="txtCHan_event" CssClass="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code. The first is that you pass `this` as the argument to `isNumberKeyDotAllowed` while you should pass `event`:

```
onkeypress="return isNumberKeyDotAllowed(event);"
```

The second is the validation condition. Here is my own version of the function. I defined the condition for success instead of the condition for failure, because it is easier for me to figure out:

```
function isNumberKeyDotAllowed(evt) {
    var charCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 46 || (48 <= charCode && charCode <= 57)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note to the OP that the keypress event does not fire on things like pasting in text

Comment: @dman2306 - Yes. In fact, it fires for `V` if the pasting is done with `Ctrl+V`. With the code above, a valid number cannot be pasted this way.

Comment: @ConnorsFan hello. sir it's not working. Instead of . it's allowing - hyphen :/

Comment: According to my tests, it works. You must have typed `charCode == 45` instead of `charCode == 46`. Did you copy/paste my code as it is?

Comment: In which browser/version and on what OS are you testing?