# Why doesn't my javascript function allow dot but instead allows hyphen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I am using this code to allow only digits to type in textbox but now I want to allow `.` too. I modified this code but instead of allowing `.` it allows hyphen `-`.

```
function isNumberKeyDotAllowed(evt) {
    var charCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 46 || (48 <= charCode && charCode <= 57)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

button:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxAreaSqft" OnTextChanged="txtBoxAreaSqft_TextChanged"
                                                    PlaceHolder="Enter Digits Only" onkeypress="return isNumberKeyDotAllowed(event)" Enabled="true" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: charCode vs. keyCode take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4285801/5433027

Comment: not working. please figure out the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my code doesn't allow specific symbols?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655470/why-my-code-doesnt-allow-specific-symbols)

Comment: yes but that doesn't answer the question that's why

Answer (score 0):

Just try Once in html onKeydown instead of onKeypress might help as i thing so its updating value mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onkeydown="return isNumOrDot(event)" />

<script>
function isNumOrDot(e){
    var nums = [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,190/*dot*/,
                96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,/*Num keys*/
                110 /*num dot*/];
    return nums.indexOf(e.which)>-1;
}
</script>
```

onkeydown="**return**... is the key.